# How parse email content with javax.mail?

Tags: java, email, message, attachment

I am trying to parse e-mails using javax.mail. I want to fetch both text content AND all attachments (preferrably INLINE pictures/attachments too).

I have the following code but it seems to break with more complex mails with several nested multiparts.

I have read the FAQ and googled the entire day without finding a solution.

Please help.

```
public static String fetchEmailcontent(Part message, String messageid) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(1024);

        if (message != null && message.getContent() != null) {
            if (message.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart parts = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                BodyPart p;
                boolean alternative = parts.getContentType().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("multipart/alternative") ? true : false;

                InputStreamReader isr;
                int retrieved;
                char[] buffer = new char[512];
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.getCount(); i++) {
                    p = parts.getBodyPart(i);

                    if (p.getContentType().toLowerCase().startsWith("multipart")) {
                        sw.write(fetchEmailcontent(p, messageid));
                        break;
                    } else if ((Part.INLINE.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getDisposition()) || p.getDisposition() == null) && p.getContentType().toLowerCase().startsWith("text") && p.getFileName() == null) {

                        if (InputStream.class.isInstance(p.getContent())) {
                            InputStream ip = p.getInputStream();

                            StringWriter subwriter = new StringWriter(ip.available());
                            isr = new InputStreamReader(ip);
                            while (isr.ready()) {
                                retrieved = isr.read(buffer, 0, 512);
                                subwriter.write(buffer, 0, retrieved);
                            }
                            sw.write(subwriter.toString());
                        } else {
                            Object content = p.getContent();
                            if (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.class.isInstance(content)) {
                                int bcount = ((java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) content).available();
                                byte[] c = new byte[bcount];
                                ((java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) content).read(c, 0, bcount);
                                sw.write(new String(c));
                            } else {
                                sw.write(content.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        if (alternative && !"".equals(sw.toString().trim())) {
                            break;
                        }
                        sw.write("\r\n");
                    } else if (p.getDisposition() != null && (p.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT) || p.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE))) {
                        saveFile(MimeUtility.decodeText(p.getFileName()), p.getInputStream(), messageid);
                    }
                }
            } else if (message.getContentType().toLowerCase().startsWith("text")) {
                sw.write(message.getContent().toString());
            }
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

Here's an example of a mail it failed to fetch the attachments from:
(I have removed headers and the BASE64-code for the attachments to save space.. they are perfectly fine otherwise)

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=f46d04016b4779522904c58fb5b4

--f46d04016b4779522904c58fb5b4
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=f46d04016b4779522104c58fb5b2

--f46d04016b4779522104c58fb5b2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test


sdljpjdpjsd


=E5=E4=F6

--f46d04016b4779522104c58fb5b2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div>test </div><div>=A0</div><div>=A0</div><div>sdljpjdpjsd</div><div>=A0<=
/div><div>=A0</div><div>=E5=E4=F6</div>

--f46d04016b4779522104c58fb5b2--
--f46d04016b4779522904c58fb5b4
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="blah.jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_h50rhk180

BUNCH OF BASE64
--f46d04016b4779522904c58fb5b4
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="blah2.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah2.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_h50ria042

BUNCH OF BASE64
--f46d04016b4779522904c58fb5b4--
```

The expected output is the text in the message body AND all the attachments saved to disk. The function saveFile() does that but its so elementary I decided not to include it. I know for sure it is not the culprit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide us with what email that is supposed to be displaying info on? Also, explain what is wrong with the attachments it found

Comment: I have attached the email source in my original post. The problem is that it did NOT find the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

In your code...

`if (InputStream.class.isInstance(p.getContent()))` can be false, however,
`InputStream ip = p.getInputStream();` can still be successful!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think your answer stops in half. For what should it help? To highlight missing return value checking? If so, just name it ;)